# El uso del “Ser de un/a + adj que” “Rogelio es de un orgulloso que a veces resulta insoportable”

Tags: gramática

> Rogelio es de un orgulloso que a veces resulta insoportable.

Me gustaría cuando se usa esta expresión. ¿Se puede usar en esta expresión adjetivos?

> Patricio es de un inteligente que pudo contestar todas las preguntas en el examen en 3 minutos.

Comment: Hausmeister33: has realizado muchas preguntas en poco tiempo, ojalá te estén sirviendo. Intenta utilizar [edit] para formatear las preguntas (más o menos como está haciendo quien te las edita para mejorar) y añadirle etiquetas relevantes. Después, puedes aceptar y/o votar las respuestas que recibes, como se explica en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Coincido con @fedorqui en cuanto a que el usuario Hausmester33 debiera producir alguna forma de valoración, respuesta o retroalimentación en sus preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente yo no he escuchado esa combinación. Para mí es muy común escuchar cosas como:

Rogelio **es de un orgullo que** a veces es insoportable.

Patricia **es de un genio que** ni ella misma se soporta.

la forma realmente en la que yo utilizo esa expresión es

*persona* **es de un sustantivo que** *cláusula_de_consecuencia*.

y el significado infiere que la persona en cuestión poseé tal grado del sustantivo que es ineludible la consecuencia establecida.

la manera más traducible que puedo pensar de esas expresiones es:

Rogelio **es tan orgulloso que** a veces es insoportable.

Patricia **es tan geniuda que** ni ella misma se soporta.

Desconozco si el uso de adjetivo en lugar de sustantivo es aceptable, yo nunca lo había escuchado así, pero me supongo que tiene el mismo sentido.

Espero haber sido claro.